# Is it possible to have two gridviews for dhtmlx scheduler?

Tags: html, gridview, scheduler, dhtml

I'm trying to display two gridviews using the dhtmlx scheduler library. The way we are using the scheduler is so that employees can sign out. Right now, we can view it as a monthly view but we also want to have a day view too.

I was able to create the grid, but when I try to click button it does not display the day report.

Here is a code snippet

```
                    scheduler.locale.labels.grid_tab = "Month";

                    scheduler.createGridView({
                       name:"grid",
                       fields:[     // defines columns of the grid
                             {id:"date", label:'Date', sort:'date', width:300, align:"left"},
                             {id:"employee",   label:'Employee',   sort:'str',  width:400, align: "*"},
                             {id:"room_description", label:'Destination', sort:'str',  width:600, align:'left'}
                       ],
                        paging:true,
                        unit:"month",
                        step:1




                });


                    scheduler.locale.labels.grid_tab2 = "Day Report";   
                scheduler.createGridView({
                       name:"day_grid",
                       fields:[     // defines columns of the grid
                             {id:"date", label:'Date', sort:'date', width:300, align:"left"},
                             {id:"employee",   label:'Employee',   sort:'str',  width:400, align: "*"},
                             {id:"room_description", label:'Destination', sort:'str',  width:600, align:'left'}
                       ],
                        paging:true,
                        unit:"day",
                        step:1

                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work on scheduler demos
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/snippet/b9320394

The only thing is that you need to define label for a day_grid view correctly, the variable should be named "day_grid_tab" instead of "grid_tab2"
scheduler.locale.labels.day_grid_tab = "Day Report";

Comment: Thanks that was it. Such a small thing to overlook.